# Instance Tag Info using boto3 : Getting None object

Tags: python, python-2.7, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3

My python code is as follow and need help with the same. Thanks

```
    import boto3
    import yaml

    def get_all_running_instances(unique_name):
        """
        Returns instance data for given instance id.
        :param unique_name:
        :return:
        """
        count = 1
        rname = unique_name.rsplit('-', 1)[0] + '-' + str(count)
        print rname
        ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2')
        instances = ec2.instances.filter(Filters=[{'Name': 'instance-state-name', 'Values': ['running', 'pending']}])
        for instance in instances:
          print(instance.id, instance.instance_type)
        for instance in instances:
          for tag in instance.tags:
                if rname in tag['Value'] and "Name" in tag['Key']:
                    count = count + 1
                    rname = rname.rsplit('-', 1)[0] + '-' + str(count)
        return count
    x = get_all_running_instances('test-1')
    print x
```

---

Output is as follows and is not able to get the tag information associated with each of the instance. 
I am running a Lambda on the tag information returned as part of this function.

```
    ('i-08987804493yyyyyy82', 't2.medium')
    ('i-0e96754xxxxxxxxx', 't2.small')
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "dummy.py", line 30, in <module>
        x = get_all_running_instances('test-1')
      File "dummy.py", line 23, in get_all_running_instances
        for tag in instance.tags:
    **TypeError**: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

Comment: Thank you so much HelloV. That did the trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are assuming all instances have at least one tag. In your case, there are instances with no tags which causes your code to fail. Instead, you can check if tags are present before iterating on `tags`.

```
for instance in instances:
  if instance.tags:
    for tag in instance.tags:
```

The above code will ignore the instances that have no tag defined. You can modify the code to suit your needs. To verify this, you can also print the tags when you are printing the `instance-id` and `instance-type`.

```
for instance in instances:
  print(instance.id, instance.instance_type, instance.tags)
```